# Magento 2 - Category page sorting does not work on grouped products

Tags: magento2, magento-enterprise, sorting, product-prices, category-page

I added the new product sorting attribute related to `price` in category page like `price low to high` and `price high to low`. It showed on `Sort By` drop down. It is working fine for configurable product and simple product but the problem is, it is working grouped products case.

Grouped product shows the price of their `lowest simple product price` in category page.

> For Reference please see the screenshot

[image]

> For Reference I use code for price sorting

```
$collection->getSelect()->order("price_index.final_price asc");
```

Any help, experience and knowledge sharing would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this `sorting` problem by using `minimal_price` instead of `price_index.final_price`.

It will work for product types including `simple`, `configurable` and `Grouped`

Here is code for that

```
//For Descending order
$collection->getSelect()->order("minimal_price desc");

//For Ascending order
$collection->getSelect()->order("minimal_price asc");
```

I hope this will help others who are facing a similar kind of sorting problem in category page/product listing page.